# How set global variable that load at start

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'd like to save global variables in a settings file to be available when the app starts. The file should be read before anything else and would contain the paths for the stores to the external image folders.

```
var pathToOriginalsFolder = "/eboydb_test/images/originals";
var pathToOriginalsRetinaFolder = "/eboydb_test/images/originalsretina";
```

The problem is they are not loading before the stores for CollectionFS are loaded and I get `ReferenceError: pathToOriginalsFolder` is not defined.

I've tried to place the settings.js file in lib, lib/loadfirst, rename it to a.js – anything to get loaded first but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you include the `settings.js` at the top of your document, before any other script files are included?

Comment: Why does settings.js have to be in a seperate file? if you dont have many javascript files you could just add the settings at the top of the main file.

Or as the user above suggested, try putting it in the head of your document and loading your other scripts before the closing body tag.

Comment: Some things may be loades asynchronous. If you are loading files, images ,etc, you need  provide callback method when your data is ready.

Comment: Turns out the variables couldn't be accessed because they weren't global. Just had to remove `var` – and rename the settings.js to a.js (to be loaded first). Now it works. Thanks and sorry to waste your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

The variables couldn't be accessed because they weren't global. This works (the 'var' in the declaration is removed):

```
pathToOriginalsFolder = "/eboydb_test/images/originals";
pathToOriginalsRetinaFolder = "/eboydb_test/images/originalsretina";
```

I also had to rename the settings file to a.js to be loaded before collection.js.